# directive can not ''require:ngRepeat'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

I write below directive to make call a function when `ngRepeat` element gets rendered on UI.

**Directive**

```
directives.directive('repeatDone', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngRepeat',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (scope.$last) {
                scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

But it is giving `$compile` error.
If I remove require part, it works OK.

Why AngularJS can not accept "require: 'ngRepeat'"?
Help would appreciated.

Comment: `require: 'ngRepeat'` This will cause a compile error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`require` is used for accessing the controller of another directive. But `ng-repeat` does not have a controller. Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js) for `ng-repeat`, the word controller doesn't even appear in the code. The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) also makes no mention of a controller for `ng-repeat`.

Typically, when you use `require` it's because you want to call functions of the required controller. In the link function for your directive you've added the argument `ngModel` -- which is what would be populated with the controller if it existed. But you never use this `ngModel` argument in the code. It's not really clear why you need to use `require` at all in this case.

**EDIT**:

On further review, perhaps you're trying to require `ng-repeat` because your `repeat-done` directive won't work outside the context of an `ng-repeat`. If that's the reason, another solution might be to traverse the DOM looking at the parent elements of your `repeat-done` directive to see if they have the attribute 'ng-repeat'. If not found, your directive could throw an error. But that seems like a lot more code w/little return on investment...

Comment: Good answer.
I think the face meaning of "require" make me confused.
**"require" in directive means need a controller or ngModel for next steps, not this directive must be used related to something.**

Answer (score 2):

You should you `$timeout` before evaluating a scope. Because when you write code inside timeout, `$timeout` will run exactly after current digest cycle gets complete.

Or you can use `scope.$evalAsync` instead of `scope.$eval`

> **$timeout** which implicitly calls $apply() after a delay & $apply runs $digest cycle
>   call exactly after DOM redered element on browser
>
> **$evalAsync** maintain async queue, and gets called after digest cycle 
>   call exactly before DOM redered element on browser

**CODE**

```
directives.directive('repeatDone', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (scope.$last) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
                });
                //or you can use 
                //scope.$evalAsync(attrs.repeatDone);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks.